# kaspersky pure2 prevents metro applications to run

Tags: windows-8

within days iv'e been working with windows 8 build9200 iv'e found that when you install kaspersky pure 2 , it prevents some metro apps to run and after metro apps shoe splash screen they just brought me back to metro default UI , i tried to put all low restricted windows services and applications to trusted level but doesn't work , normally it happens when UAC set to off but i refreshed windows and everything worked fine , installed kapser again and some metro apps just doesn't run , as an example it doesn't affect all metro applications my chrome works fine in metro interface , i don't know if there is a possible solution or not ?!

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky released newer version of Kaspersky PURE 2.0... Download at http://products.kaspersky-labs.com/english/homeuser/pure2/pure12.0.2.733en.exe.

Comment: i find my self easier to user internet security as it meets my needs and let pure go for a while

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Kaspersky web site and Pure is indicated now to be compatible with windows 8. I installed and again I cannot launch any Metro application (Store, Contacts...)
This is boring. My subscription is running and I cannot use it :(

Comment: as i commented for the other guy you may use kaspersky internet security 2013 which im using right now , and there would be no problem with metro applications , i , u and so many people had reported this problem but it seems by now they dont care